# caching the redirects in varnish with apache backend

Tags: apache, redirect, varnish

I have an apache server running on a different host than that of varnish server. If we hit on apache server's ip, it redirects to apache_ip/index.php/Main_Page.

Since this apache server is the backend server for varnish, I always get a 301 response from varnish.

```
sh-4.3# curl 172.16.217.59 -v
* Rebuilt URL to: 172.16.217.59/
*   Trying 172.16.217.59...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.16.217.59 (172.16.217.59) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.16.217.59
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 18:00:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Debian)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
< Cache-Control: s-maxage=1200, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 18:00:03 GMT
< Location: http://172.16.217.173/index.php/Main_Page
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-Varnish: 32789 32787
< Age: 1003
< Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 172.16.217.59 left intact
```

How can i configure the varnish server to handle this redirection? I wish to go to the redirection location and cache its contents.

Answer (score 0):

If think that the best solution would be to use a hostname, like something.com, and point it to your Varnish server and configure the Apache server to recognize it too.

But if you cannot do that you can change your Varnish VCL configuration to rewrite the request to change the host header, and to change the Location header from response, something like this should solve the problem:

```
sub vcl_rev {
  set req.http.host = "172.16.217.173";
} 

sub vcl_fetch {
  if (beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
    set beresp.http.Location = regsub(beresp.http.Location, "172\.16\.217\.59", "172.16.217.213");
  }
}
```

I didn't test the code above but it should works.

This way the Apache will be receiving always the correct Host header and Varnish will be sending the redirects with the Varnish IP address instead of the ip address from Apache

Comment: @ShivamMitra I still thinks that the best way would be using hostnames, that would save you the headache of messing with rules on VCL, but you should be able to solve the problem with my lats edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to make varnish follow the redirect. The 301 response is meant to be interpreted by the client not really by the proxies even if it is possible.

A better approach would be to use hostnames as Dimas said.

Create yoursite.com
Make it point to your varnish
register it on your apache configuration
make it the default hostname on apache (so the redirects contain it instead of the server ip)

Other solutions are hacks. You can either : in varnish when you have the backend response, parse it and change the location header to replace your apache server ip by your varnish server one, or instead implement a retry logic and follow the redirect (still in the backend_response subroutine).